# Что означает фамилия Кириченко?

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Скажите, пожалуйста, каково происхождение довольно распространенной фамилии Кириченко? Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Как я полагаю, пришло некогда имя "Кирилл" (имя, как предполагают, из др.-греч. kyrios - "господин, владыка) в западную славянскую культуру (туда, где сейчас Украина и западная Беларусь), где немного трансформировалось: приобрело некие местные суффиксы и неизменяемость украинских фамилий, после чего стало фамилией, ныне очень распространенной.